# How to open modal view on button click?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I want to open modal view on button click.

This is my html page where i have my button and when iclick this button i wan to open modal view, which i have in separate html file.

```
<ion-view >
<ion-content>
<div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
<div id = "map-list" >
 <button ng-click="modal.show()">show modal</button>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This is my modal html code.

```
    <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">New Contact</h1>
      <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Cancel</button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
          <input ng-model="newUser.firstName" type="text">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
          <input ng-model="newUser.lastName" type="text">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Email</span>
          <input ng-model="newUser.email" type="text">
        </label>
        <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="createContact(newUser)">Create</button>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
```

It is not working. Should i add any functionality in controller?
Please give me advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<ion-modal-view id="myView">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">New Contact</h1>
      <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Cancel</button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
          <input ng-model="newUser.firstName" type="text">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
          <input ng-model="newUser.lastName" type="text">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Email</span>
          <input ng-model="newUser.email" type="text">
        </label>
        <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="createContact(newUser)">Create</button>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
```

In controlller

```
$scope.showModal = function(){
  var msgBoxSmall = angular.element('#myView');
    msgBoxSmall.modal('show');
}
```

In Html

```
<ion-view >
<ion-content>
<div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
<div id = "map-list" >
 <button ng-click="showModal ()">show modal</button>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: it is not working. I am getting this error ->Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!

Comment: refer jquery in your index.html file.